# Create xarray dataset dynamically from multiple files

Tags: python, python-xarray

I would like to create an xarray dataset from several input files.
each file is for 1 timestamp, 1 level and 1 source.
An example with 2 timestamps, 2 levels and 3 sources:

```
d1 = np.arange(0,9).reshape((3,3))   # 01:00, 3m, SG1 -> 00001-101.con
d2 = np.arange(10,19).reshape((3,3)) # 01:00, 3m, SG2 -> 00001-102.con
d3 = np.arange(20,29).reshape((3,3)) # 01:00, 3m, SG3 -> 00001-103.con
d4 = np.arange(60,69).reshape((3,3)) # 01:00, 10m, SG1 -> 00001-201.con
d5 = np.arange(70,79).reshape((3,3)) # 01:00, 10m, SG2 -> 00001-202.con
d6 = np.arange(80,89).reshape((3,3)) # 01:00, 10m, SG3 -> 00001-203.con

e1 = np.arange(100,109).reshape((3,3)) # 02:00, 3m, SG1 -> 00002-101.con
e2 = np.arange(110,119).reshape((3,3)) # 02:00, 3m, SG2 -> 00002-102.con
e3 = np.arange(120,129).reshape((3,3)) # 02:00, 3m, SG3 -> 00002-103.con
e4 = np.arange(160,169).reshape((3,3)) # 02:00 10m, SG1 -> 00002-201.con
e5 = np.arange(170,179).reshape((3,3)) # 02:00 10m, SG2 -> 00002-202.con
e6 = np.arange(180,189).reshape((3,3)) # 02:00 10m, SG3 -> 00002-203.con


dstk = np.stack((d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6)) # 01:00, both levels all sgs -> 00001-101.con - 00001-203.con
estk = np.stack((e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6)) # 02:00, both levels all sgs -> 00002-101.con - 00002-203.con
```

i managed to manually create the dataset in the way i need it like this:

```
xx = [100,200,300]
yy = [600,700,800]

dds1 = xr.Dataset(data_vars={"SG1":(("x","y"),dstk[0]),"SG2":(("x","y"),dstk[1]),"SG3":(("x","y"),dstk[2])},coords={"x":xx,"y":yy,"lvl":"3m","t":pd.Timestamp("2010-01-01 01:00:00")})
dds2 = xr.Dataset(data_vars={"SG1":(("x","y"),dstk[3]),"SG2":(("x","y"),dstk[4]),"SG3":(("x","y"),dstk[5])},coords={"x":xx,"y":yy,"lvl":"10m","t":pd.Timestamp("2010-01-01 01:00:00")})

eds1 = xr.Dataset(data_vars={"SG1":(("x","y"),estk[3]),"SG2":(("x","y"),estk[4]),"SG3":(("x","y"),estk[5])},coords={"x":xx,"y":yy,"lvl":"3m","t":pd.Timestamp("2010-01-01 02:00:00")})
eds2 = xr.Dataset(data_vars={"SG1":(("x","y"),estk[3]),"SG2":(("x","y"),estk[4]),"SG3":(("x","y"),estk[5])},coords={"x":xx,"y":yy,"lvl":"10m","t":pd.Timestamp("2010-01-01 02:00:00")})

td1 = xr.concat([dds1,dds2],dim="lvl")
td2 = xr.concat([eds1,eds2],dim="lvl")

td_final = xr.concat([td1,td2],dim="t")
```

which gives me this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lvl: 2, t: 2, x: 3, y: 3)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int32 100 200 300
  * y        (y) int32 600 700 800
  * lvl      (lvl) <U3 '3m' '10m'
  * t        (t) datetime64[ns] 2010-01-01T01:00:00 2010-01-01T02:00:00
Data variables:
    SG1      (t, lvl, x, y) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 ...
    SG2      (t, lvl, x, y) int32 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 70 71 72 73 74 ...
    SG3      (t, lvl, x, y) int32 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 80 81 82 83 84 ...
```

However, this seems way too complicated, and i´d like to create the dataset dynamically by for example looping over lists of timestamps, sourcegroups and levels.

Comment: Is `eds1` supposed to be constructed from `estk[0], etsk[1], etsk[2]`? Right now it looks like a duplicate of `eds2`.